# Will my project source most of its current from the battery?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current, 5v

I have a video game controller project that requires a battery. This is because the console doesn't provide enough current on the 5V rail to fully power the project. The battery (and charge circuit) is more than capable of running the project by itself, but I do need to connect the 5V rail from the console to the project anyway, since it provides just enough current for the microcontroller to turn on and send a signal to the battery to wake up from sleep mode. After the battery is woken up, will the project source most of the current from the battery, or is it still going to try pulling current from the 5V rail on the console?

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: How are the battery and the console power connected together? Post a schematic. (You don't need to show the whole circuit, just the part where power comes in)

Comment: @user253751 I don't quite have a schematic for this; just been prototyping on a breadboard. The 5V line from the console goes into the VIN pin on the microcontroller, with a diode so the battery won't backpower the console. The 5V from the charge circuit goes into the VIN pin of the microcontroller as well. Nothing else is currently attached, save for ground pins.

Comment: Well then draw one.

Comment: @user253751 https://imgur.com/a/ITIJAer

Comment: how does one "wake up" a battery?

Comment: Bad design.  If you do it like you drew it (one diode) then the console will charge the battery when it gets depleted enough. You don't want THAT happening (unless you like cleaning up leaky batteries).   Put a diode on BOTH same way you have it, then the battery will not push current into the console, the console will not push current into the battery, and the micro will source current from whichever source can supply it at the time.     There are far more complex and elegant ways to do this, but the two-diode approach is perfectly suitable for your purpose.  I might add a capacitor there.

Answer (score 0):

The 5V power rail can only have one voltage at a time.

If the console voltage is more than 0.6V above the 5V power rail, current will flow through the diode until it isn't (0.2V if it's a Schottky diode). If it's less than that, it won't.

Since the 5V power rail is directly connected to the battery, the voltage on the 5V power rail is always equal to the voltage coming from the battery.

You do the math.

Comment: Both the console voltage and the battery are 5V, not two separate voltages. The console voltage is only there to power the microcontroller long enough to wake up the battery. But I'm looking for an answer to the question of if the project will use the battery more than the console, thus not burning up the console.

Comment: @sharkeylaser Well, is 5V more than 0.6V above 5V?

Comment: @sharkeylaser:  The console voltage and battery are both **nominal** 5V.  In reality, neither will be exactly 5V.  There will always be a small difference, and that will determine which source will end up powering the circuit.

Comment: @sharkeylaser Physics doesn't care that they are both supposed to be the same. Physics cares about what is *actually there*. For example, the battery voltage is 0V (high impedance) when the battery is off, right? Even though you call it 5V? (I assume it is not the battery itself that is off, but some kind of battery controller circuit)